# React Native (Android) - How to know if the cell phone is receiving GSM signal?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I wonder if there is some package of react-native that detect GSM signal?

I am not really interested in strength but at least the "ServiceState"  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html) but using React Native.

The following packages no detect GSM:
Nor Netinfo ("react-native-community/netinfo"),
Nor expo-signal,
Nor "react-native-device-info"
Nor "react-native-carrier-info"

For example NetInfo in this case gives "null" but I still can send sms.

If there is no package, how is the easiest way to do it using react-native structure.

Thank you!